# how to establish host to host communication using qt

Tags: qt

a client module is connected to server, now can a separate program executed by the server module using system() write in the same socket? if yes how ..

or should the client program open a different socket for this?

Answer (score 1):

If your server is based on Qt, you'd rather use [QProcess](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qprocess.html).
Now, I don't understand what you want to do : if 2 persons are allowed to interact with any resource, you'll have to cleanly control the way they interact.

On of the easiest way is to use [QSharedMemory](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qsharedmemory.html) : your main server process controls the socket, starts a shared memory, then exec your other software.
While your other software is running, your main application transfer data from/to the socket to the shared memory, and your spawned process interacts only with the shared memory.